# Plotly warning in R when plotting volcano plot: ignoring observations

Tags: r, plot, plotly, warnings

I am using plotly in R to generate a volcano plot. When I call the plot, it looks fine, but I also get an error:

`Warning message: Ignoring 5 observations`

How do I find out what these 5 observations are? Or why they are being ignored?
I need to check if there is a problem with these 5 data points. I have visually inspected my data, and can't see any problem, but it is a huge dataset so I could be missing something.

Could anyone advise with some debugging steps please?

EDIT: I'm not sure if it will help, as I suspect the problem is with my data, not code, but here is the code I'm using, with simplified data.

```
library(plotly)
name <- c("Name1", "Name2", "Name3")
log2FoldChange <- c(-2.7419374, 2.9655255, -1.7455225)
padj <- c(2.25e-27, 3.01e-24, 2.56e-25)
df <- data.frame(name, log2FoldChange, padj)
my_plot <- plot_ly(data = df,
                       x = df$log2FoldChange, 
                       y = -log10(df$padj))
```

Comment: Please provide your code so we can help you

Comment: Generally when `ggplot2` or `plotly` couldn't figure out a way to plot observations, they ignore them. This is common with `NA`, `NaN` values. Also if you are using some calculation function (like some `stat` function), they might also ignore values if they aren't able to calculate values.

Comment: @monte It can also be out-of-bounds value on the panel range, so I ndon't agree when you say ignore them.

Comment: @MonJeanJean, I agree but I meant ggplot ignores them, not you should ignore them

Comment: @monte Ho ok, sorry for that missunderstood

Comment: @MonJeanJean I thought about doing that but I suspect the problem is more with my data than the actual code, and my data is very large and I wouldn't be allowed share it anyway

Comment: @monte Good ideas, thank you. But I have checked that all my entries are numeric with the `is.numeric()` function, and searched specifically for NA and NaN entries - apparently there are none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regards to your question, I see you are using `log10` function to calculate y-axis points, please note that log is not defined for negative numbers (and 0). Those values will produce `NaN` and will be ignored.

In regards to broader question, how to see what data is being plotted on, with both `ggplot` and `plotly` you can extract the data, but with `plotly` I found it hard to find which data isn't plotted.

```r
library(palmerpenguins)
#> Warning: package 'palmerpenguins' was built under R version 4.0.5
invisible(library(tidyverse))
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 4.0.3
invisible(library(plotly))

randomRows = sample(1:nrow(penguins), 10) #to replace any 10 rows with NA

penguins[randomRows, "body_mass_g"] = NA

penguins %>% 
  ggplot(aes(bill_length_mm, body_mass_g)) +
  geom_point() -> plot_ggplot

plot_ggplot
#> Warning: Removed 11 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

[image]

As you can see, it throws the warning that rows has been ignored.

To get the plot data:

```r
head(ggplot_build(plot_ggplot)$data[[1]])
#>      x    y PANEL group shape colour size fill alpha stroke
#> 1 39.1 3750     1    -1    19  black  1.5   NA    NA    0.5
#> 2 39.5 3800     1    -1    19  black  1.5   NA    NA    0.5
#> 3 40.3 3250     1    -1    19  black  1.5   NA    NA    0.5
#> 4   NA   NA     1    -1    19  black  1.5   NA    NA    0.5
#> 5 36.7 3450     1    -1    19  black  1.5   NA    NA    0.5
#> 6 39.3 3650     1    -1    19  black  1.5   NA    NA    0.5
```

The `x` and `y` columns represents your x and y axis.

In case of `plotly` there is a similar way to extract data, but it just shows, only those points which are plotted. I couldn't figure out a way to extract the values which are being ignored.

```r
pp = plot_ly(penguins, x=~bill_depth_mm, y=~body_mass_g, type='scatter')
plotly_build(pp) -> plotly_data
#> No scatter mode specifed:
#>   Setting the mode to markers
#>   Read more about this attribute -> https://plot.ly/r/reference/#scatter-mode
#> Warning: Ignoring 11 observations
#> Warning: `arrange_()` was deprecated in dplyr 0.7.0.
#> Please use `arrange()` instead.
#> See vignette('programming') for more help

names(plotly_data$x$data[[1]])
#>  [1] "x"       "y"       "type"    "mode"    "marker"  "error_y" "error_x"
#>  [8] "line"    "xaxis"   "yaxis"   "frame"

#this gives your x-axis data
plotly_data$x$data[[1]]$x[1:5]
#> [1] 18.7 17.4 18.0 19.3 20.6

#this gives your y-axis data
plotly_data$x$data[[1]]$y[1:5]
#> [1] 3750 3800 3250 3450 3650
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much for such a thorough answer! I was able to figure it out from this, there were indeed some `NAs` lurking in there.